# App crashed with "Error inflating class android.support.design.chip.Chip" after updated to support library version 28.0.0-rc02

Tags: android, android-support-library, layout-inflater, android-chips

I have got the the error "**Error inflating class android.support.design.chip.Chip. This component requires that you specify a valid TextAppearance attribute. Update your app theme to inherit from Theme.MaterialComponents (or a descendant).**" after updated to support library version **28.0.0-rc02**. The Application was working properly with previous support library version 28.0.0-alpha1.

Currently, I am using Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar and should I change to Theme.MaterialComponents according to the error message or is there anyway to solve?

[image]

[image]

Comment: The error message seems pretty clear. Have you tried it?

Comment: This chip view has been added into 28. I am amazed that how you were using in 27.1.0

Comment: Got it now. Thanks @ianhanniballake.

Comment: Sorry @PankajKumar. I wrongly checked with previous's previous version. The version I previously used is 28.0.0-alpha1.

Answer (score 3):

After I updated the theme to **Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.NoActionBar**, the error is gone. Thanks @ianhanniballake.

I haven't tried before because I **misunderstood** the following sentence from the [doc](https://material.io/develop/android/docs/getting-started/) (between dependencies and themes).

> Note: You should not use the com.android.support and com.google.android.material dependencies in your app at the same time.

Comment: permit me to love you! *wink*